# Query mutiple collection at once in mongo based on matching criteria

Tags: mongodb, mongo-cxx-driver

I want to write aggregate function to select all name having TCS across collection in one call -

**How can i write to fetch all name having TCS in one call?**

```
    db.stocks.find()
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5d81e624ae6a505982c1c409"), "name" : "Infosys", "qty" : 100, "price" : 800 }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5d81e624ae6a505982c1c40a"), "name" : "TCS", "qty" : 100, "price" : 2000 }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5d81e624ae6a505982c1c40b"), "name" : "Wipro", "qty" : 2500, "price" : 300 }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5dbea62c608aba164b7c869b"), "name" : "TCS", "qty" : 0, "price" : 800 }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5dbea62c608aba164b7c869c"), "name" : "TCS", "qty" : 0, "price" : 2000 }
    db.stocks1.find()
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5d81e652ae6a505982c1c40c"), "name" : "Infosys_1", "qty" : 100, "price" : 800 }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5d81e652ae6a505982c1c40d"), "name" : "TCS_1", "qty" : 100, "price" : 2000 }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5d81e652ae6a505982c1c40e"), "name" : "Wipro_1", "qty" : 2500, "price" : 300 }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5d81f013ae6a505982c1c40f"), "name" : "Infosys", "qty" : 200, "price" : 800 }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5d81f013ae6a505982c1c410"), "name" : "TCS", "qty" : 200, "price" : 2000 }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5d81f013ae6a505982c1c411"), "name" : "Wipro", "qty" : 3500, "price" : 300 }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5dbea5dd608aba164b7c8698"), "name" : "TCS", "qty" : 0, "price" : 800 }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5dbea5dd608aba164b7c8699"), "name" : "TCS", "qty" : 0, "price" : 2000 }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5dbea5dd608aba164b7c869a"), "name" : "TCS", "qty" : 4500, "price" : 300 }
    db.stocks2.find()
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5d81f0ceae6a505982c1c412"), "name" : "Infosys", "qty" : 300, "price" : 800 }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5d81f0ceae6a505982c1c413"), "name" : "TCS", "qty" : 300, "price" : 2000 }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5d81f0ceae6a505982c1c414"), "name" : "Wipro", "qty" : 4500, "price" : 300 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is **not possible**.

The only thing in mongo that you can use to query other collections from one collection is **`$lookup`**, for that also you will need a **referring key** and a **referred key** in the respective collection (***your collection don't have those***).

Even providing dummy key in localField and foreignField in the $lookup stage will fetch data from stock1 when we are querying stocks, but the structure of the whole result will be very weird, and will only get worse when you try to fetch data from stocks2. You will have to much duplicate docs, and you have to do a lot of post-processing to filter out the result and present it in the proper format.

Best is you **query them separately**, and fetch the result, this will be faster than doing a lot of post-processing.

Or you can change the schema, and try adding keys to refer another collection from one collection.

**SUGGESTION:**

From your data in stocks, stocks1, stocks2, they have same fields,

**so why not to merge them one collection itself mainStocks**,

such that, **mainStocks** has all the docks from all three stocks, stocks1, stocks2 **AND** will have all new docs that are meant to be inserted either in stocks or stocks1 or stocks2.

**Basically, all CRUD operation should be done on mainStocks that are being done on stocks, stocks1, stocks2.**